# Single form for multiple lists

Tags: custom-form, custom-list

Is there any chance to do that? If so, what do you suggest me to do? I have two custom lists that are related to each other, while adding an item to main list, i have to add some parts of it into another list simultaneously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier to implement option than an event receiver is a Workflow, triggered by the first list, to insert data from that entry into another list.

This can be easily built using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Just as a hint: Afaik a SPD 2010 Workflow has the limitation that it only cycles through five elements of an list, after 5th it collapses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Item receiver](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/Event%20Receivers.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If to answer the question in title "Single form for multiple lists", then, IMO,  the most effective solution is to publish an Infopath form template as Sharepoint content type.

I could have written about it in more details but the body of text is asking/describing something completely unrelated to title for which I would have configured site columns which again I could have extended if I was more sure in context and details

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use SharePoint Designer workflows. You can define there actions that can update items on other lists. Event receiver would also be great, but I don't think there's a need to any custom development here.

If you are not into SharePoint Designer or coding event receivers, try to look at this one:
http://www.articlesbase.com/software-articles/put-your-sharepoint-lists-to-work-with-smart-action-pro-5221059.html